# how to get children row within the same table of parent in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need your advice guys on how can I query this scenario.

I have a `Table Thread` and the fields are:

```
-id 
-author_id
-content_id
-parent_id
-type
```

and here are the rows in table thread:

```
id   author_Id   content_id  parent_id  type
1    3           60                      3
2    3           1           1           2
3    3           2           1           2
4    3           61                      3
5    3           1           4           2
6    3           2           4           2
7    3           63                      1
8    3           62                      1
```

How can I query the parents that include the children? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get a list of the children with the parent's data, this [query](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3112c/3) should work:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.author_id, t1.content_id, t1.type, IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(t2.id), '') as children
FROM Thread t1
LEFT JOIN Thread t2
ON t2.parent_id = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Output:

```
id  author_id   content_id  type    children
1   3           60          3       2,3
2   3           1           2   
3   3           2           2   
4   3           61          3       5,6
5   3           1           2   
6   3           2           2
```

To only get data for parents with children, change the `LEFT JOIN` to a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.author_id, t1.content_id, t1.type, IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(t2.id), '') as children
FROM Thread t1
JOIN Thread t2
ON t2.parent_id = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Output:

```
id  author_id   content_id  type    children
1   3           60          3       2,3
4   3           61          3       5,6
```

Comment: it works. I have a minor issue. I update my list of rows in table thread. I add row 7 and row 8. When I try your query. It includes the row 7 and row 8. I only want those data that have a children. thanks for your reply

Comment: Just change the `LEFT JOIN` to a `JOIN`

Comment: No worries. There's a good short tutorial on JOINs [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)